# Can I bring methylated spirits camping fuel into Russia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, russia

Apparently, [methylated spirits / methyl alcohol / ethanol is very hard to find in Russia](http://www.mark-ju.net/juliette/meths.htm), so I am considering to bring mine on the train.  According to [this page](https://www.moscovery.com/customs-and-border/) (not an official source), it is prohibited to bring *Toxic and explosive materials* into Russia.  Would that include camping fuel?  It's not entirely explosive but it's certainly toxic!  Can I bring a couple of liter with me on the train into Russia?

Comment: If it were the old Russia, I'd say don't bother, just buy strong cheap vodka there.

Comment: @RayButterworth What is the old Russia and does such vodka actually burn properly?

Comment: Traditionally, Russia was famous for cheap and plentiful high-proof vodka, some of which was close to pure ethanol, similar to the US Hillbilly white lightning ["moonshine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonshine).  I meant is mostly as a joke, though perhaps in poor taste given this: ["How Alcohol Conquered Russia"](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2013/09/how-alcohol-conquered-russia/279965/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to "[Goods, prohibited or limited for transfer via the customs border of the Eurasian Economic Union](http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1686&Itemid=1908)" (where Russia is a member state),

> List of the goods for the personal usage, prohibited to import into
>   the customs territory of the Eurasian Economic Union (hereinafter -
>   the Union) and (or) export from the territory of the Union

includes

> 3.4 poisonous substances, which are not the precursors of the narcotic drugs and psychotropic substances

Unfortunately, I am not able to find the list of poisonous substances in English, only in [Russian](http://eec.eaeunion.org/ru/act/trade/catr/nontariff/Documents/2.13%20-%20yad.doc) (even though [the page](http://eec.eaeunion.org/en/act/trade/catr/nontariff/Pages/ediny_perechen.aspx) you download the list from is in English). Anyhow, methanol is number 15 there.

Edit:
If you would like to bring ethanol to Russia, you are allowed to do so (up to 5 liters). However, according to Decision of the Council of the Eurasian Economic Commission​​ dated 20.12.2017 N 107 (as amended on 01.11.2018) "On certain issues related to the goods for the personal use" ([only in Russian](https://docs.eaeunion.org/docs/ru-ru/0044719/cncd_19032018_107)), you need to pay 22 EUR for each liter.

Comment: Conclusion: it is prohibited to bring the camping fuel?

Comment: Conclusion: it is prohibited to bring methyl alcohol to Russia. 
However, I am pretty sure you can buy the camping fuel in a camp shop if you start your journey from a big city.

Comment: Are you sure I can easily buy it?  I've found many sources saying it's hard to find, such as I linked in the question or [(1)](https://pikabu.ru/story/gde_kupit_spirt_4284062), [(2)](https://forum.ykt.ru/viewtopic.jsp?id=4323603), [(3)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lada.commerce/wNfr7AzEA30). Are they talking about something else?

Comment: I've asked a related [question on Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/22462/566)

Comment: Also merely a comment because I've no direct experience, but this thread  _https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/russia/hiking-camping-store-in-moscow_  may have relevant content for you.